# Place content from top and centre align it in the wrapper div that has height and width 100%

Tags: html, css

I need to place the content one below the other from the top and center align it.

I tried making all the **rows** positioning them **absolute** and making the 
**top:20% ,top:40% ,top:60% respectively** and **margin: 0 auto** does not work.So I had to put left percentages for all three rows.

It looks rubbish when I reduce width of browser and when I reduce the height of the browser the **divs** overlap each other

I do not want **overflow:auto or overflow-y:scroll** .I want the content to be placed in that 100% height of wrapper and centered perfectly.How to implement this and also suggest me how to do it in **media queries** ?

[image]
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="row1">Long Text</div>
<div id="row2">Long Text</div>
<div id="row3">Long Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#row1{
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
}

#row2{
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
}

#row3{
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: you want output similar to image

Comment: yes I want the output similar to the image.

Comment: flexbox + vw/vh units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do like this

```css
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{background: #333;}
#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.w1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#row1{
    height: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#row2{
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
        background: #fff;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#row3{
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
        background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="w1">
    <div id="row1">Long Text</div>
<div id="row2">Long Text</div>
<div id="row3">Long Text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i wanted.But here each row is equally spaced.what if i wanted different spacing between the rows.

Comment: you can change spacing, height, width as you need. Its just example

Comment: here row2 margin:10px auto controls the equal spacing between the other two.I am asking.If I wanted 200px spacing between row1 and row2 and 300px spacing between row2 and row3.What should I do?

Comment: anyway possible to make your code responsive.adding percentages vs media queries.which one is better.

Comment: another VW trick is good but its not support anywhere so you can use percentage for spacing and width instead of pixels

Answer (score 1):

> It looks rubbish when I reduce width of browser and when I reduce the
>   height of the browser the divs overlap each other

Use percent units (or vw) instead of pixels.

> I want the content to be placed in that 100% height of wrapper and
>   centered perfectly

Use `flex` on the container, with appropriate width and heights on the children.

**Example Snippet**:

```css
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around; /* to distribute space evenly around */
}
#wrapper > div { background-color: #ddd; }
#row1 { flex: 0 0 20%; width: 50%; } /* 0 0 means cannot grow cannot shrink */
#row2 { flex: 0 0 10%; width: 80%; }
#row3 { flex: 0 0 40%; width: 65%; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Long Text</div>
    <div id="row2">Long Text</div>
    <div id="row3">Long Text</div>
</div>
```

**Sample Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/j3js87fc/1/

---

### Update:

Alternatively, you could just use appropriate top/bottom margins on the `row2` to have differing gaps between rows.

**Example 2**:

```css
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
#wrapper { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#wrapper > div { background-color: #ddd; }
#row1 { height: 20%; width: 50%; margin: auto; } 
#row2 { height: 10%; width: 80%; margin: 3% auto 7% auto; }
#row3 { height: 40%; width: 65%; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">Long Text</div>
    <div id="row2">Long Text</div>
    <div id="row3">Long Text</div>
</div>
```

**Sample fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/j3js87fc/4/

.

Comment: Here each row is equally spaced.what if i wanted different spacing between the rows.

Comment: @Vishwas: Added an update to the answer. Change the top/bottom margin on the middle row to have differing gaps between rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/oh36f1zb/4/

The `left:50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` does all the trick.